# python3 manage.py runserver error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I try to start (python3 manage.py runserver) my django2.0 webapp on my PC I have this message:

Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x7fc889c36510>
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 538, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in **get**
    res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/neo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 545, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

my app's code :

(/django-examples/mysite):

(Setting.py)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'webexample',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

(urls.py)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls')),
]
```

(/django-examples/mysite/webexample):

(urls.py)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

(views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
return HttpResponse("<h3>Hello, world!</h3>")
```

ubuntu 16.04
django 2.0.4
python 3.5
pip 8.1.1

What can be a reason of problem?

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok (apart from the indentation), and shouldn't cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

> [The order of `INSTALLED_APPS` is significant!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'webexample',
]
```

Comment: I reinstalled my OS and all the software. Now my code is the same as yours
The errors from the console are gone, but I still can't get this "Hello, world" signature:

Answer (score 0):

To add your apps to settings.py in the main project folder, you need to write the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    '*AppName*.apps.*Class*',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

The AppName will be the name if your app, Class must be obtained from *apps.py* in your App folder. 
Here the AppName seems to be *webexample*, and the name of the only class in its *apps.py* will replace the class.
I hope this will resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have rest framework or mysql, then you need to mention it in the installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_mysql',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('webexample.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Project urls.py should be changed like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('webexample.urls')),
]
```

View.py should be changed like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h3>Hello, world!</h3>")
```